# Accordeon webpage scrolling wrong

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, web

I am working on my website and I just cannot solve one problem I have with a javascript issue:

I have an accordeon type of page what i call now menu and I can open/slide the topics down when I click on them, where more infos will appear on that topic. 
I am using smooth scrolling done in JS. 
I structured it in "accmain" for accordeon and "accsub" for the content appearing when you click on the accmain.
As I want the transition between two topics to be smooth, I want the last "accmain" to close the according "accsub", then smoothly go to the new "accmain", align it on the top and open the new "accsub".

Now so far everything is just fine. 
Only problem I do run into is when You open another topic while one is still open: 
It does not align the new accmain to the top, but shifts the whole scroll about the height of the "accsub" which was opened before, but should be closed now. So the new topic is not aligned to top but eventually shifted so far (depending on the last topic and it's height) that You can't see anything of it.
It is actually a pretty simple problem i guess, though I am very new to especially javascript, but I know that it is exactly shifting for the amount of pixels of the accsub before. that's a start :)

here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/BrtkJrtk/tw19rn1u/#&togetherjs=iNcRR4Sxkb)

thanks everyone, I do appreciate any help.
I am spending now a few weeks on excactly that problem.

```js
/* multi-toggle accordion*/
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".accsub").hide();
  $('.accmain').click(function() {
    $( this ).toggleClass( "miau100" );
    if ($(this).next().is(":visible")) {
      $(this).next().slideUp('fast');
      $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this).offset().top - 150
      }, 'slow');
      $( this ).toggleClass( "miau75" );
    } else {
      $('.accsub:visible').slideUp('fast');
      $(this).next().slideDown('fast');
      $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
      }, 'slow');
    }
  });
});

/* GO TO TOP BUTTON */
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a[href='#top']").click(function() {
    $('.accsub:visible').slideUp('fast');
    $("html, body").animate({
      scrollTop: 0
    }, "slow");
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,100i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i,900,900i');
header > .accmain {
  height: 150px;
}

p1 > .accmain:hover {
  color: grey
}

footer {
  min-height: 150px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.beitrag {}

.accmain {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 3em;
  background-color: #FFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #585858;
  padding: 1px;
  color: #585858;
  opacity: 0.75;
}

.accmain:hover {
  /*   background-color: #b3b3b3;  */ 
  transition: ease-in-out 0.7s;
  color: black;
  opacity: 1.0;
}

.miau100 {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

.miau75 {
  opacity: 0.75;
}


.accsub {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  /* horizontale zentrierung = wenn column dann align-items: center; ansonsten justify-content: center;*/
  background-color: #FFF;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #625750;
  padding-left: 10%;
  padding-right: 10%;
}

.imagewrap img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.topbutton {
  position: fixed;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  top: 90%;
  left: 90%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  font-size: 2em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  transition: ease 0.7s;
}

.topbutton:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  transition: ease 0.7s;
}

.text {
  width: 722px;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.newspaper {
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  /* Firefox */
  column-count: 2;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-style: light;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 26.4px;
  margin-top: 80px;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
  max-width: 722px;
}

.newspaper2 {
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  /* Firefox */
  column-count: 2;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-style: light;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 26.4px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  max-width: 722px;
}

.newspaper3 {
  -webkit-column-count: 1;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-count: 1;
  /* Firefox */
  column-count: 1;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 26.4px;
  max-width: 722px;
  align-items: left;
}

h1 {
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-style: light;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 26.4px;
}

h2 {
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-style: bold;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 15.4px;
}

h3 {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-style: bold;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 15.4px;
}

p {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 20px;
}

p1 {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #A4A4A4;
  margin-left: 10px;
}


pre {
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 18.5714px;
  align-items: left;
}

blockquote {
  font-family: Garamond, Baskerville, "Baskerville Old Face", "Hoefler Text", "Times New Roman", serif;
  font-size: 21px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 30px;
}

hr {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de-de">

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="Bartek Juretko" content="Künstler">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <link rel="icon" href="favicon.png" sizes="16x16" type="image/png">


  <body class="all">

    <header>
      <div class="accmain">
        <!-- erstes kind-->
        <div class="text">
          <h2>BARTEK JURETKO</h2></div>
      </div>
      <div class="accsub">

        <div class="newspaper">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex
          ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit
          augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy
          nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit
          in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor
          cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat
          volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore
          eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming
          id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum.
        </div>
      </div>


    </header>


    <div class="beitrag">
      <div class="accmain">
        <div class="text">
          <h1>AStA Cafe<p1>27.01.2015</p1></h1></div>
      </div>
      <div class="accsub">

        <div class="newspaper">Astacafe Hagen, Kunstakademie Duesseldorf
          <br>
          <br>
          <br> Fertigstellung und Eroeffnung
          <br>
          <br> Der Umbau des Astacafes in der Kunstakademie Duesseldorf hat einen kroenenden Abschluss gefunden: Am 27. Januar 2015 um 19 Uhr wurde das Cafe feierlich eroeffnet. Zur Eroeffnung gab es feinste Koestlichkeiten in Form eines vier Gaenge Menues.
          <br> Das Astacafe hat Mo-Fr von 12-19 Uhr geoeffnet.
          <br>
          <br> Mit Louisa Rossner, Duesseldorf, 2014-15
          <br>
          <br>
        </div>

        <div class="imagewrap">
          <img src="http://www.umbraframework.de/2270.jpg">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="beitrag">
      <div class="accmain">
        <div class="text">
          <h1>Ausführung Service-Theke im Sparta<p1>18.04.2017</p1></h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="accsub">

        <div class="newspaper2">
          Fertigstellung und Eroeffnung
          <br>
          <br> Der Umbau des Astacafes in der Kunstakademie Duesseldorf hat einen kroenenden Abschluss gefunden: Am 27. Januar 2015 um 19 Uhr wurde das Cafe feierlich eroeffnet. Zur Eroeffnung gab es feinste Koestlichkeiten in Form eines vier Gaenge Menues.
          <br> Das Astacafe hat Mo-Fr von 12-19 Uhr geoeffnet.
          <br>
          <br> Mit Louisa Rossner, Duesseldorf, 2014-15
        </div>
        <div class="imagewrap">
          <img src="http://www.umbraframework.de/2270.jpg">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="beitrag">
      <div class="accmain">
        <div class="text">
          <h1>Publikation im Salon Magazin Nr.4<p1>04.2017</p1></h1></div>
      </div>
      <div class="accsub">
        <?php
echo date("d.m.Y H:i:s");
?>
      </div>
      <div class="imagewrap"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="beitrag">
      <div class="accmain">
        <div class="text">
          <h1>Kunstakademie Düsseldorf Rundgang 2017, Teilnahme<p1>02.2017</p1></h1></div>
      </div>
      <div class="accsub">subcontent...</div>
      <div class="imagewrap"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="beitrag">
      <div class="accmain">
        <div class="text">
          <h1>kunstakademie.gallery, Ausstellungsteilnahme&Tab;<p1>12.2016</p1></h1></div>
      </div>
      <div class="accsub">subcontent...</div>
      <div class="imagewrap"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="beitrag">
      <div class="accmain">
        <div class="text">
          <h1>'art-hoc' im Reservat, Ausstellungsteilnahme&Tab;<p1>12.2016</p1></h1></div>
      </div>
      <div class="accsub">subcontent...</div>
      <div class="imagewrap"></div>
    </div>






    <div class="beitrag">
      <div class="accmain">
        <div class="text">
          <h1>kunst kann's 2016, Kunstauktion Teilnahme<p1>11.2016</p1></h1></div>
      </div>
      <div class="accsub">subcontent...</div>
      <div class="imagewrap"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="beitrag">
      <div class="accmain">
        <div class="text">
          <h1>kunstakademie.gallery, Ausstellungsteilnahme<p1>08.2016</p1></h1></div>
      </div>
      <div class="accsub">subcontent...</div>
      <div class="imagewrap"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="beitrag">
      <div class="accmain">
        <div class="text">
          <h1>TOTAL, Ausstellungsteilnahme<p1>08.2016</p1></h1></div>
      </div>
      <div class="accsub">subcontent...</div>
      <div class="imagewrap"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="beitrag">
      <div class="accmain">
        <div class="text">
          <h1>ad absurdum im HINTERZIMMER, Ausstellung<p1>08.2016</p1></h1></div>
      </div>
      <div class="accsub">subcontent...</div>
      <div class="imagewrap"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="beitrag">
      <div class="accmain">
        <div class="text">
          <h1>Cafe RAT und TAT, Aktion und Ausstellung<p1>08.2016</p1></h1></div>
      </div>
      <div class="accsub">subcontent...</div>
      <div class="imagewrap"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="beitrag">
      <div class="accmain">
        <div class="text">
          <h1>Absolventenstipendium 2016 der Freunde und Förderer<p1>07.2016</p1></h1></div>
      </div>
      <div class="accsub">subcontent...</div>
      <div class="imagewrap"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="beitrag">
      <div class="accmain">
        <div class="text">
          <h1>Baukunstkammer, Abschlussausstellung und Akademiebrief<p1>07.2016</p1></h1></div>
      </div>
      <div class="accsub">subcontent...</div>
      <div class="imagewrap"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="beitrag">
      <div class="accmain">
        <div class="text">
          <h1>'art-hoc' in den Ex-Achenbach-Hallen, Ausstellungsteilnahme<p1>03.2016</p1></h1></div>
      </div>
      <div class="accsub">subcontent...</div>
      <div class="imagewrap"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="beitrag">
      <div class="accmain">
        <div class="text">
          <h1>Trockenbauwand<p1>04.2016</p1></h1></div>
      </div>
      <div class="accsub">subcontent...</div>
      <div class="imagewrap"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="beitrag">
      <div class="accmain">
        <div class="text">
          <h1>Habe Meine Hölzer Sortiert<p1>03.2016</p1></h1></div>
      </div>
      <div class="accsub">subcontent...</div>
      <div class="imagewrap"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="beitrag">
      <div class="accmain">
        <div class="text">
          <h1>Kunstakdemie Düsseldorf Rundgang 2016, Teilnahme<p1>01.2016</p1></h1></div>
      </div>
      <div class="accsub">subcontent...</div>
      <div class="imagewrap"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="beitrag">
      <div class="accmain">
        <div class="text">
          <h1>Nischenpreis, Wettbewerbsteilnahme<p1>01.2016</p1></h1></div>
      </div>
      <div class="accsub">subcontent...</div>
      <div class="imagewrap"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="beitrag">
      <div class="accmain">
        <div class="text">
          <h1>Friesenberg Heidelberg, Entwurf<p1>11.2015</p1></h1></div>
      </div>
      <div class="accsub">subcontent...</div>
      <div class="imagewrap"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="beitrag">
      <div class="accmain">
        <div class="text">
          <h1>kunst kann's 2015, Kunstauktion Teilnahme<p1>11.2015</p1></h1></div>
      </div>
      <div class="accsub">subcontent...</div>
      <div class="imagewrap"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="beitrag">
      <div class="accmain">
        <div class="text">
          <h1>Wystawa Plastyki Zagłębia Miedziowego 2015, Ausstellungsteilnahme<p1>08.2015</p1></h1></div>
      </div>
      <div class="accsub">subcontent...</div>
      <div class="imagewrap"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="beitrag">
      <div class="accmain">
        <div class="text">
          <h1>CLASH, Ausstellung<p1>06.2015</p1></h1></div>
      </div>
      <div class="accsub">subcontent...</div>
      <div class="imagewrap"></div>
    </div>


    <div class="beitrag">
      <div class="accmain">
        <div class="text">
          <h1>Ein Europahaus für den Europatag im Düsseldorfer Rathaus<p1>09.2015</p1></h1></div>
      </div>
      <div class="accsub">Entwurf des 'Europahauses' fuer 'We Are Europe' Zum sogenannten Europatag, am 9.Mai, einem Jahrestag der bisher eher als das 'Ende des Zweiten Weltkrieges' bekannt ist, entstand ein Entwurf fuer die von der Organisation 'We Are Europe' geplante
        Aktion aus Kartons ein Haus fuer Europa zu bauen. Die Besucher beteiligten sich aktiv an einer Beschriftung der Bausteine mit Werten, die sie mit Europa verbinden, und bauten so Stein fuer Stein das 'Europahaus' im Duesseldorfer Rathaus. Duesseldorfs
        Oberbuergermeister Thomas Geisel fing mit dem Grundstein an und eroeffnete zusammen mit der NRW-Ministerin Dr. Schwall-Dueren und dem Vorsitzenden von We Are Europe Jens Baganz um 11 Uhr die Aktion. Mit Aneta Dobozi, Duesseldorf, 2015 2. Foto:
        Melanie Zanin 4. Foto: We Are Europe www.duesseldorf.de www.we-are-europe.org </div>
      <div class="imagewrap"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="beitrag">
      <div class="accmain">
        <div class="text">
          <h1>Bauhausmuseum Dessau, Wettbewerbsbeitrag<p1>03.2015</p1></h1></div>
      </div>
      <div class="accsub">

        <div class="imagewrap">
          <img src="http://www.umbraframework.de/2270.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <div class="newspaper2">
            <br>Teilnahme Realisierungswettbewerb
            <br>
            <br>Staedtebaulich wirkt das Museum wie ein Solitaer umgeben von Vegetation, differenziert betrachtet unterscheiden sich die Geschosse: das Erdgeschoss adaptiert die Baufluchten der Ratsgasse, positioniert zwei Baukoerper in der Verlaengerung
            der sich in der Ratsgasse gegenueberstehenden Fassadenreihen und schafft dazwischen einen Hof, als gleich einen Durchgang zum Park in direkter Forfuehrung der Ratsgasse. Wie im Cartesischen Dualismus stehen sich im Erdgeschoss zwar zwei Entitaeten
            gegenueber, werden aber im oberen Geschoss miteinander vereint zu einem einheitlichen Ganzen: der Ausstellungshalle, die als Buegel ueber beiden erdgeschossigen Koerpern schwebt. Es ist ein komplimentaeres Tor: von der Stadt zum Park und vom
            Park zur Stadt. Die Ausstellunghalle ist ganz bewusst angelehnt an den Gedanken von grossen Messehallen, die Flexibilitaet und Moeglichkeiten bewahren, um der Ausstellungsarchitektur mehr Freiraum zu lassen.
            <br>
            <br>Dessau, 2015</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="beitrag">
      <div class="accmain">
        <div class="text">
          <h1>Kunstakademie Düsseldorf Rundgang 2015, Teilnahme<p1>02.2015</p1></h1></div>
      </div>
      <div class="accsub">subcontent...</div>
      <div class="imagewrap"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="beitrag">
      <div class="accmain">
        <div class="text">
          <h1>AStA Cafe Hagen, Fertigstellung<p1>01.2015</p1></h1></div>
      </div>
      <div class="accsub">subcontent...</div>
      <div class="imagewrap"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="beitrag">
      <div class="accmain">
        <div class="text">
          <h1>Helsinki Guggenheim Museum, Wettbewerbsteilnahme<p1>10.2014</p1></h1></div>
      </div>
      <div class="accsub">subcontent...</div>
      <div class="imagewrap"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="beitrag">
      <div class="accmain">
        <div class="text">
          <h1>Kleine Brötchen Backen, Performance<p1>08.2014</p1></h1></div>
      </div>
      <div class="accsub">subcontent...</div>
      <div class="imagewrap"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="beitrag">
      <div class="accmain">
        <div class="text">
          <h1>Jaana Caspary VERSUS Bartek Juretko, Ausstellung<p1>08.2014</p1></h1></div>
      </div>
      <div class="accsub">subcontent...</div>
      <div class="imagewrap"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="beitrag">
      <div class="accmain">
        <div class="text">
          <h1>AStA Cafe Hagen in der Kunstakademie, Entwurf<p1>04.2014</p1></h1></div>
      </div>
      <div class="accsub">subcontent...</div>
      <div class="imagewrap"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="beitrag">
      <div class="accmain">
        <div class="text">
          <h1>17,98 EUR<p1>02.2014</p1></h1></div>
      </div>
      <div class="accsub">subcontent...</div>
      <div class="imagewrap"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="beitrag">
      <div class="accmain">
        <div class="text">
          <h1>Mercedes-Benz, Workshop<p1>2013/2014</p1></h1></div>
      </div>
      <div class="accsub">subcontent...</div>
      <div class="imagewrap"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="beitrag">
      <div class="accmain">
        <div class="text">
          <h1>Gestaltung Rundgangscafe, Vorschlag<p1>12.2013</p1></h1></div>
      </div>
      <div class="accsub">subcontent...</div>
      <div class="imagewrap"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="beitrag">
      <div class="accmain">
        <div class="text">
          <h1>Gerresheimer 100, Ausstellung<p1>10.2013</p1></h1></div>
      </div>
      <div class="accsub">subcontent...</div>
      <div class="imagewrap"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="beitrag">
      <div class="accmain">
        <div class="text">
          <h1>Den Toten Ihre Namen Geben, Engere Auswahl Wettbewerbsbeitrag</h1></div>
      </div>
      <div class="accsub">subcontent...</div>
      <div class="imagewrap"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="beitrag">
      <div class="accmain">
        <div class="text">
          <h1>Faerber, Ausstellungsteilnahme</h1></div>
      </div>
      <div class="accsub">subcontent...</div>
      <div class="imagewrap"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="beitrag">
      <div class="accmain">
        <div class="text">
          <h1>Stadt der Zukunft, Workshop</h1></div>
      </div>
      <div class="accsub">subcontent...</div>
      <div class="imagewrap"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="beitrag">
      <div class="accmain">
        <div class="text">
          <h1>Stadthaus in Wien, Wettbewerbsbeitrag</h1></div>
      </div>
      <div class="accsub">subcontent...</div>
      <div class="imagewrap"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="beitrag">
      <div class="accmain">
        <div class="text">
          <h1>Upcycling Berlin, Ausstellungsteilnahme</h1></div>
      </div>
      <div class="accsub">subcontent...</div>
      <div class="imagewrap"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="beitrag">
      <div class="accmain">
        <div class="text">
          <h1>Keine Kunst</h1></div>
      </div>
      <div class="accsub">subcontent...</div>
      <div class="imagewrap"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="beitrag">
      <div class="accmain">
        <div class="text">
          <h1>Brücke im Landschaftsschutzgebiet, Wettbewerbsbeitrag</h1></div>
      </div>
      <div class="accsub">subcontent...</div>
      <div class="imagewrap"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="beitrag">
      <div class="accmain">
        <div class="text">
          <h1>Upcycling Berlin, Wettbewerbsgewinn</h1></div>
      </div>
      <div class="accsub">subcontent...</div>
      <div class="imagewrap"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="beitrag">
      <div class="accmain">
        <div class="text">
          <h1>Keine Kunst</h1></div>
      </div>
      <div class="accsub">subcontent...</div>
      <div class="imagewrap"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="beitrag">
      <div class="accmain">
        <div class="text">
          <h1>Bibliothek in Daegu, Wettbewerbsbeitrag</h1></div>
      </div>
      <div class="accsub">subcontent...</div>
      <div class="imagewrap"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="beitrag">
      <div class="accmain">
        <div class="text">
          <h1>Findlinge Seminar auf der Architektur Biennale in Venedig</h1></div>
      </div>
      <div class="accsub">subcontent...</div>
      <div class="imagewrap"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="beitrag">
      <div class="accmain">
        <div class="text">
          <h1>Keine Kunst</h1></div>
      </div>
      <div class="accsub">subcontent...</div>
      <div class="imagewrap"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="beitrag">
      <div class="accmain">
        <div class="text">
          <h1>Architektur AG an der GGS Marienstrasse</h1></div>
      </div>
      <div class="accsub">subcontent...</div>
      <div class="imagewrap"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="beitrag">
      <div class="accmain">
        <div class="text">
          <h1>Entwurf Mehrfamilienwohnhaus in Indien</h1></div>
      </div>
      <div class="accsub">subcontent...</div>
      <div class="imagewrap"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="beitrag">
      <div class="accmain">
        <div class="text">
          <h1>Autodidaktische Weltkarte</h1></div>
      </div>
      <div class="accsub">subcontent...</div>
      <div class="imagewrap"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="beitrag">
      <div class="accmain">
        <div class="text">
          <h1>Neuer Entwurf für ein Grabmal</h1></div>
      </div>
      <div class="accsub">subcontent...</div>
      <div class="imagewrap"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="beitrag">
      <div class="accmain">
        <div class="text">
          <h1>Ny Valer Kirke, Wettbewerbsbeitrag</h1></div>
      </div>
      <div class="accsub">subcontent...</div>
      <div class="imagewrap"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="beitrag">
      <div class="accmain">
        <div class="text">
          <p>Impressum</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="accsub">subcontent...</div>
      <div class="imagewrap">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <a href="#top" class="topbutton">&#x2303;</a>
    </div>

    <footer>
      <a href="#top">Zum Anfang der Seite Scrollen</a>
    </footer>

</html>
```

Comment: $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this).offset().top - $('.accsub').offset().top
      }, 'slow');

here is the problem as I see it: I need to tell him that he has to scroll on top, but minus the height of the actual element .accsub as a child of .accmain. I just don't understand why nothing works :D

Answer (score 0):

maybe this could be a solution for you:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".accsub").hide();
    $(".accmain").click(function(){
    $(".accsub").hide();
        $(this).next(".accsub").slideToggle("fast");
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this).offset().top - 1
    }, 'slow');
    });

});
```

I guess you want to align the accmain- container to the top of the browser on each klick on it.
and don't forget to put "GO TO THE TOP" inside `$(document).ready(function(){YOUR ENTIRE CODE GOES HERE}`, so that your code waits for the document to be loaded.